# Call someone with Twilio then disconnect me and play a message to other person

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to create a button on a webpage (on my presonal PHP webserver) that should connect me (either call my cellphone or via the webclient), then call a number, I then want to have an options to either hangup the call, or just disconnect me but play an mp3 to the other person and then hangup.

I'm not sure how to go about it. I created a TwiML, but how do I connect that to the existing call? Or is there a different way to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Play>https://something-something.twil.io/assets/recording1.mp3</Play>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you definitely want to speak to the person first and then hang up yourself or would this work if the call was just made directly to the third party?

Comment: I would like to transfer them only if I hear an answering machine. If it's a live person, I would talk to them and disconnect from them when I'm done, and then connect to another person on my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to do. You have a list of people you're trying to call. The app will call them and connect you. If you hear an answering machine, you want to press a key then hangup and move on to the next call. But after you hang up, that first outbound call stays online and leaves a .mp3 message to that recipient?

I believe one solution would be creating a conference with a bot.

Your app makes an outbound call to you, to the bot and to the recipient and puts everyone into a conference room called "room-timestamp" where timestamp is the current time. The bot is a twilio number that listens for a Gather dtmf. If you press 1, it will play message 1 then hang up. But because this is a conference, you can hangup at anytime and move on to the next call.
The bot could loop a few times and if no dtmf is detected, it will hang itself up.
This is all made easier using the new Outbound conference API where you can pass it the conference name instead of conference SID :

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list-post

Edit:

Connect three numbers to a conference room :

```
$uniqueid = time();
$call = $client->account->calls->create($officeline,$twilionum,
```

array("url" => "http://yourdomain/conference.php?id=$uniqueid"));

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create($botline,$twilionum,
```

array("url" => "http://yourdomain/conference.php?id=$uniqueid"));

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create($customerline,$twilionum,
```

array("url" => "http://yourdomain/conference.php?id=$uniqueid"));

This will connect three numbers to a conference room:

- $officeline (your number),
- $botline (twilio phone # of a bot that responds to dtmf)
- $customerline (the customer you're calling)

conference.php just returns a conferenceID for calls to connect to:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

$confid = $_REQUEST['id'];
echo<<<XMLOUT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<Response>
<Dial>
<Conference statusCallbackEvent="leave" statusCallback="killconference.php">$confid</Conference>
</Dial>
</Response>

XMLOUT;
```

killconference.php is called so that the conference can be terminated when there's only one person left. Just make sure your bot hangs up after playing something.

killconference.php

```
 $theconference = $_REQUEST['ConferenceSid'];

 $participants = $client
    ->conferences($theconference)
    ->participants
    ->read();


 if (count($participants) == 1) {

   $conference = $client
    ->conferences($theconference)
    ->fetch();

   $conference->update(array(
        "Status" => "completed"
    ));

 }
```

your botline twilio number will be pointing to bot.php that responds to dtmf:

bot.php

```
   header('Content-Type: text/xml');

   $dtmf = isset($_REQUEST["Digits"]) ? $_REQUEST["Digits"] : "";
   $playmore = "";
   if ($dtmf == "1") {
       $playmore = "<Say>Hey I just wanted to leave you a message </Say><Hangup/>\n";
   }
   if ($dtmf == "2") {
       $playmore = "<Play>http://www.soundboard.com/mediafiles/22/224470-33a9f640-d998-45a3-b0c1-31c1687c2ae4.mp3</Play><Hangup/>\n";
   }


echo<<<XMLOUT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Response>

$playmore
<Gather action="bot.php" numDigits="1" timeout="30">
</Gather>
<Hangup/>

</Response>

XMLOUT;
```

The bot will stay on the line for 30 seconds, if no dtmf is entered it hangs itself up. Press 1 to leave the customer a message, 2 for Leroy Jenkins

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. So I need to buy a Twilio number and set it up as a bot (so I would initiate a call to the bot AND to me AND the other person). Correct? Or is there a way to connect a bot to an existing conference?

Comment: I like @philnash method of using your web browser as the dialer and moving more of the logic there.If you want to have an office line ring and a bot join the call, see the code I added in. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is an ideal use case for [Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection). With Twilio's answer machine detection you can set it to `Enabled` or `DetectMessageEnd` which means that you can use Twilio to work out whether a machine has answered the call and wait until the message is over then play it a message. Otherwise you can connect the call to yourself.

With PHP, you can generate the call like this:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
$token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    "+14155551212", "+14158675309",
    array(
      "url" => "http://example.com/calls",
      "MachineDetection" => "DetectMessageEnd"
    )
);
```

Then, for your URL, you need to respond to the call depending on what the machine detected. You do that with the [`AnsweredBy` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection#new-webhook-parameters). Something like this, which [dials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) your number if someone answers or speaks a message using [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) if a machine answers:

```
<?php
  if ($_REQUEST['AnsweredBy'] == "human") {
    echo "<Response><Dial><Number>YOUR_NUMBER</Number></Dial></Response>";
  } else {
    echo "<Response><Say>Hello, this is my message</Say></Response>";
  }
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Edit**

### Without Answering Machine Detection

Ok, to do this without Answering Machine Detection I recommend you build yourself a dialler using [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js). There is a [quickstart guide here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript), so I won't go through how that works here.

Once you have a dialler you can use it to initiate the phone calls. The issue is then moving the voicemail calls to play the message. I would build two buttons, one that hangs up as if you've completed the call successfully and the other that plays the message instead. The first button is a simple function call to [`Twilio.Device.activeConnection().disconnect()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#disconnect_1).

The second one needs a couple of things. The idea is that it will make a call to your server to redirect the other call to a new set of TwiML.

First up, you need the SID of the call you created. You can get that from the connection object you receive in response to calling `connect`.

```
var connection = Twilio.Device.connect({ number: "+1234567890" });
var callSid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
```

When you want to hangup and play a message you need to send this to your server. This is the SID of the parent call though, and you need to get the child call, the other leg. So, on your server you need to [use the REST API to get the other call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list), then [redirect it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
$token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$calls = $client->calls->read(
    array("ParentCallSid" => $_REQUEST['CallSid'])
);
// Loop over the list of calls, it should only have one call in it, and redirect the call to a URL that has the message TwiML
foreach ($calls as $call) {
    $call->update(array(
        "url" => "http://example.com/message.xml"
    ));
}
```

When you redirect the child call, the parent call will no longer be connected so it will hang up. The URL you redirect the child call to should contain the TwiML required to play the message to the machine using [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play).

Comment: I didn't want to use the answering machine detection, since (it works great for answering machines, but) humans hear a gap of a few seconds. Also, if I'm on the line/conference before the machine answers, I can say "hello John" and then play the message.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to provide a different answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: @Bmore yes exactly. I have hung up so many times when I hear this. Robo calls are the worst so using Twilio and not using machine learning is a good thing in this case as its mean to the receivers if its not a legit call.